# I cannot access the MAC address of another computer in the network

Tags: node.js, npm, mac-address

I am using the [macfromip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/macfromip) module available in npm. I want to access the mac address of the other computer on the same network with the IP information.Yesterday I was able to access the mac address with the macfromip module.

```
var macfromip = require('macfromip');

macfromip.getMac("192.168.XXX.XXX", function(err, data){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    data = JSON.stringify(data) ;
    macaddress = data ;
    //macaddress = macaddress.replaceAll("-",":");  

    console.log("mac:",(macaddress));


});
```

But when I run the project today, I get the following output instead of the mac address;

```
56.1 --- 0x3
  I
```

I don't even know what that means. I did not make any changes to the project. I'm not sure why that is either. I would be glad if you help.

Comment: I would recommend looking for an alternative, `macfromip` makes all kinds of assumptions regarding the output of the command line utilities it uses that aren't guaranteed to yield a valid MAC address (as you have already noticed).

Comment: It works fine on one computer and not on the other. This didn't make much sense to me. Could it be a problem with permissions?

Comment: If it were a permissions issue I would have expected the function to throw an error. But like I said, it's just not a very good module.

Comment: So is there any other method you can suggest? I only know the IP address of the computer whose MAC address I want to know.

Comment: I can't recommend any because I never had the need to use such a module, but there are various others: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=arp

Answer (score 1):

I also tried the [arp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/arp) library, but I could not reach the mac address. Then I discovered that the problem was caused by the WLAN. Due to the WLAN setting made on my computer, the two computers were in different WLANs. This causes the macfromip library to work incorrectly. After getting both computers to the same WLAN, the problem was solved.